# MVVM - how much can a view know about other ViewModels?

Tags: .net, mvvm

I'm trying to work out the best way to implement my design or to understand if my design is wrong in regards to MVVM approach.

The idea is my MainWindow will have 2 controls; A `Menu` (the normal, File, Edit etc) and a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` will bind to a property of my MainWindowViewModel.

When the application loads, the constructor of my MainWindowViewModel binds a property (Called CurrentView) to my  WelcomeView; it is a welcome message which has 2 buttons. 1 button is to open a new view called SearchView, the other button opens a view called AddView.

The problem I have is getting my head around how this will work.

Is my WelcomeViewModel allowed to know of the MainWindow view model? I assume note. Maybe it should call a function within App.xaml which says "I've been clicked, please close me and open the new view"?

I hope my question is clear, if not please let me know.

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear, but yes, a ViewModel can have a direct reference to another ViewModel that is perfectly valid.

Comment: @HighCore - Sorry that it is not clear, but I think you have answered it! So, let's assume my MainWindowViewModel had a property (called CurrentView). The CurrentView property of my MainWindowViewModel can be via my WelcomeViewModel (which is how I can change the View on screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is how I resolve "partial views" in WPF:

The MainView has a

`<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ActiveViewModel}"/>`,

then the MainViewModel has a

`public BaseViewModel ActiveViewModel {get;set;} //NotifyPropertyChanged, of course =)`

so whenever you change the "active ViewModel", the contentpresenter shows the View for that VM. 
As simple as that

Comment: This is exactly how I have it, even down to the naming! Strange coincidence but a happy one. This is wonderful. Thank you.